# How to make Scroll Bar set to bottom on Click?

Tags: android, scrollview

Hi I want to make Scroll Bar set to Bottom to my Activity on Button Click.
I have try using

```
final ScrollView Scrbar=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollContainer);
                    Scrbar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Scrbar.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
```

But It's not working the way I want.
How should I'll meet to my requirements?
please suggest

Comment: Any fruitful result found?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
         scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: Scrbar.scrollTo(0, Scrbar.getBottom());